# Inserting 49.000 charecter to TextView and low speed application

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I have a collection of about 500 letters and speeches some of which are really large (about 49.000 characters). I exported these letters and speeches from my MySQL and imported them into sqlite in order to use them in an Android application.

The application is working correctly and is fast for small letters. When however the user selects one of the large letters (the ones that have about 49.000 characters) it will take a long time to open the letter. What I mean by "opening" the letter is inserting the letter content into a TextView by using the `setText` function as seen below:

```
myDbHelper2 = new DataBaseHelpername(this.getApplicationContext());
    myDbHelper2= new DataBaseHelpername(this);
try {

    myDbHelper2.createDataBase();

}                   

catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
    try {

                myDbHelper2.openDataBase();}        

catch (SQLException sqle) {

    sqle.printStackTrace();

}
    db = myDbHelper2.getReadableDatabase();
    mCursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT field_translation_fa_value,my_id  FROM name WHERE my_id ="+id+" ;",null);
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    String ff=mCursor.getString(0);
    txtmatnfa.setText(ff);
```

What can I do to optimise this?

Where is the problem from? from inserting (setText) or from selecting (sqlite)?

Comment: `49,000 characters ???? OOOOOOOHHHHHHMMMMGGGGG`. You write this

Comment: I assume....nobody here can help You with a so huge data puting in  a textview.....it´s too much...

Comment: I think you should better to used `Notepad app` for this.

Comment: @MD Are you kidding? (Thanks anyway) :)

Comment: @MD can you please take a look at question again (at the end of question)

Comment: @Opiatefuchs  can you please take a look at question again (at the end of question)

Comment: @KGL As per my aspect the best way is implement `addTextChangedListener(..)` for `editText` and try to update or insert text in sqlite`

Comment: Why don't you just introduce some kind of paging system? Split large tekst into smaller pieces and let users read it like a book (49000 characters even is a small book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to read your database from another Thread, maybe using AsyncTask for example :

```
 new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                myDbHelper2 = new DataBaseHelpername(YourActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
                myDbHelper2= new DataBaseHelpername(YourActivity.this);
                try {

                    myDbHelper2.createDataBase();

                }

                catch (IOException ioe) {
                    throw new Error("Unable to create database");
                }
                try {

                    myDbHelper2.openDataBase();}

                catch (SQLException sqle) {

                    sqle.printStackTrace();

                }
                db = myDbHelper2.getReadableDatabase();
                mCursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT field_translation_fa_value,my_id  FROM name WHERE my_id ="+id+" ;",null);
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
                String ff=mCursor.getString(0);
                return ff;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String ff) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                txtmatnfa.setText(ff);
            }
        }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you cut the long text it in pieces per paragraph or so? Create a simple listview with only a textview in it an place a paragraph in a listrow. Remove the dividers (so users won't notice they are in a listview with separated paragraphs). The listview will handle that the visible paragraphs have the text they need, and your done.

And as [florent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4608166/florent-champigny) suggests in his answer, do it in a asynctask (so not in the main thread but in the background).